# Ever a need for CurrentMember.Item(0)

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

The custom measure in the following is taken from the book MDX Cookbook (Tomislav Piasevoli):

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Internet Sales PP] AS 
    Sum
    (
      Generate
      (
        {
            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080105]
          : 
            [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080125]
        }
       ,{
          ParallelPeriod
          (
            [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
           ,1
           ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Item(0)
          )
        }
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Internet Sales PP]
  } ON 0
 ,[Product].[Color].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

What purpose does the `item(0)` serve?

My understanding, which is probably wrong is

- `<set>.item(0)` gives us first tuple in set
- `<tuple>.item(0)` gives us first member in tuple

So what is the point of `<member>.item(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [this](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2010/08/how-to-use-item-and-when-item0-item0-is-redundant/) excellent article on the topic.

To sum it up, when we are doing a `.ITEM(0)` on a member, that member is implicitly converted to a tuple. So, `.ITEM(0)` does not really serve any purpose other than returning the member itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this is a typo or a copy paste error. At least in the [official Microsoft MDX reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145970), there are only the two `Item()` versions that you mention.

And this does not cause an error, as there are some implicit type conversions:

- If you have a member and need a tuple for the current expression, AS implicitly builds a one-member tuple from the member. Which is what takes place here presumably, when applying `Item(0)` to a member.
- If you have a one member tuple and need a member for the current expression, AS implicitly applies `Item(0)`.
- There are similar implicit conversions from tuple and level to set, from tuple to scalar value, from dimension to hierarchy, and from hierarchy to member.

Comment: It doesn't cause an error. I suppose `.currentmember` and `.currentmember.item(0)` are just always the same?

Comment: +1 also I've added it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e47a391-6d17-4146-9850-af75c55fe63e/why-use-currentmemberitem0?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Comment: @whytheq Yes, via implicit type conversion (see my edit)

Comment: @FankPI ...newer question added: more fun than this one! ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853929/ordering-a-complex-set