# Ordering a complex set

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I've been playing with a script of Chris Webb's found here: http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/advanced-ranking-and-dynamically-generated-named-sets-in-mdx/

The adapted script is this:

```
WITH 
  SET MyMonths AS 
    TopPercent
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
     ,20
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    ) 
  SET MyEmployees AS 
    [Employee].[Employee].[Employee].MEMBERS 
  SET MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets AS 
    Generate
    (
      MyMonths
     ,Union
      (
        {[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}
       ,StrToSet
        ("
         Intersect({}, 
         {TopCount(MyEmployees, 10, ([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],[Date].     [Calendar].CurrentMember))
         as EmployeeSet"
            + 
              Cstr(MyMonths.CurrentOrdinal)
          + "})"
        )
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[RestOfEmployees] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Except
      (
        MyEmployees
       ,StrToSet
        (
          "EmployeeSet" + Cstr(Rank([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,MyMonths))
        )
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[EmployeeRank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Employee].[Employee].CurrentMember
     ,StrToSet
      (
        "EmployeeSet" + Cstr(Rank([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,MyMonths))
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[EmployeeRank]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    Union
    (
      Filter
      (
        MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets * MyEmployees   //<<<HERE<<<<
       ,
        [Measures].[EmployeeRank] >= 1
      )
     ,{
        MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets * [Employee].[Employee].[RestOfEmployees]
      }
    )
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

How do I `ORDER` the output so that each set of ten employees is in order 1 to 10, with the `MEMBER` called `RestOfEmployees` always found in position 11 i.e. it should follow the member ranked 10 ?

The temptation is to add the `ORDER` function at the point marked `HERE` i.e. that line will become :

```
MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets * ORDER(MyEmployees, [Measures].[EmployeeRank])
```

Doing that results in the following error message:

> The dimension '[EmployeeSet0]' was not found in the cube when the string, [EmployeeSet0], was parsed.

I believe this is because the measure `EmployeeRank` uses the inline sets created during the generate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redefine `EmployeeRank` to be 11 for `RestOfEmployees`, you can just add that member to the set that is the first argument to `Filter`, and than apply `Order`, as it will sort after position 1 to 10:

```
WITH 
  SET MyMonths AS 
    TopPercent
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
     ,20
     ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    ) 
  SET MyEmployees AS 
    [Employee].[Employee].[Employee].MEMBERS 
  SET MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets AS 
    Generate
    (
      MyMonths
     ,Union
      (
        {[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}
       ,StrToSet
        ("
         Intersect({}, 
         {TopCount(MyEmployees, 10, ([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],[Date].     [Calendar].CurrentMember))
         as EmployeeSet"
            + 
              Cstr(MyMonths.CurrentOrdinal)
          + "})"
        )
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[RestOfEmployees] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Except
      (
        MyEmployees
       ,StrToSet
        (
          "EmployeeSet" + Cstr(Rank([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,MyMonths))
        )
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[EmployeeRank] AS 
    IIF([Employee].[Employee].CurrentMember IS [Employee].[Employee].[RestOfEmployees], 
        11,
        Rank
        (
          [Employee].[Employee].CurrentMember
         ,StrToSet
          (
            "EmployeeSet" + Cstr(Rank([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,MyMonths))
          )
        ) 
    )
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[EmployeeRank]
   ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
  } ON 0
 ,
   Order(
      Filter
      (
        MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets  
          * UNION(MyEmployees, {[Employee].[Employee].[RestOfEmployees]})
       ,
        [Measures].[EmployeeRank] >= 1
      ), [Measures].[EmployeeRank]
      )
  ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting answer (and question). I find this technique almost like magic, the section in `ON 1` which says `MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets  * (MyEmployees...` is difficult to understand as the set `MyMonthsWithEmployeesSets` are months crossed with empty sets (the top 10s are unioned with {}), whereas `MyEmployees` is all the emplyees - not easy for me to visualize. Any ideas on how to help my understanding?!

Comment: @whytheq To be honest, I did not try to understand all details of the long statement. I just tried to solve the question.

Comment: @FrankPI - very sensible - it has caused me to get a little bit closer to some sort of MDX nervous breakdown.

Comment: @FrankPI ...hey `LOL` ... you used a `+` operator: I'm going to edit.

Comment: @whytheq I think you refer to my remark at the end of my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886382/is-there-a-performance-gain-using-rather-than-aggregateunion I did not want to say I always prefer to write `Union` instead of `+`. I just wanted to express my opinion that it was a language design decision That I would have taken differently, had I been the one to decide. However, now that the language design is as it is, I use it as it is.

Comment: @FrankPI ..That is what I was referring to and only joking around. Feel free to edit back my edit matey - lots of people don't like edits to their answers.

Comment: (@FrankPI ..Although atleast this joke proves I'm taking notice of your advice!)