# Is there a performance gain using + rather than Aggregate(Union

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I was looking at this post in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145493.aspx

It states that + and Union are *equivalent* ... not exactly in the following as `Aggregate` needs to be applied if I choose to use `Union`.

It's more readable but is there any performance gain in choosing `+` over `Aggregate(Union` ?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[blah] AS 
      [Employee].[Employee].[Amy E. Alberts]
    + 
      [Employee].[Employee].[Garrett R. Vargas] 
  MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[blahblah] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      Union
      (
        {[Employee].[Employee].[Amy E. Alberts]}
       ,{[Employee].[Employee].[Garrett R. Vargas]}
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,{
    [Employee].[Employee].[Amy E. Alberts]
   ,[Employee].[Employee].[Garrett R. Vargas]
   ,[Employee].[Employee].[blah]
   ,[Employee].[Employee].[blahblah]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[8];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `+` is used for several purposes in MDX: as numerical addition, for string concatenation, and as union operator. And as the a member definition expects an expression that delivers a value and you use the operator between two members, and the value of the current measure is numerical, AS uses numerical addition.

If you enclose the members in braces:

```
  MEMBER [Employee].[Employee].[blah] AS 
      {[Employee].[Employee].[Amy E. Alberts]}
    + 
      {[Employee].[Employee].[Garrett R. Vargas] }
```

you get an error that AS expects string or numeric expressions for the `+` operator.

And there is probably a small performance gain, but the result may be different if the current measure is not aggregated by `sum`, which would be equivalent to adding both member values in this case.

I personally do not like this operator overloading of `+`, `*` etc. for different purposes. `+` and `*` should be restricted to numbers, be it integers, floats, or decimals. I also would also prefer another operator for string concatenation than `+` in Java, JavaScript, and .net, as well as Microsoft SQL and MDX. Standard SQL uses `||`, Perl uses `.`, so there are alternatives that clearly avoid ambiguities and you clearly know what to expect when you write `'2' || 1` vs. `'2' + 1` vs. vs. `2 + '1'` vs. `2 + 1`.

Comment: @whytheq It depends on the situation. If you are sure you have only summable measures, `+` is a simple and possibly slightly faster way to define the measure. However, `Aggregate` is the more general concept. And if you have just a few single member/tuple elements, then you can always write `{A, B, C}` instead of `{A} + {B} + {C}` or even `Union(Union({A}, {B}), {C})`.